# In Collection view in which 1st and last card view to be filled in wide screen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How to create a collection view in which we can make the 1st cell and last cell of collection in card view type display as filled in row and other cell in between showing as two items in a row.
How to implement them programmatically?

Kindly suggest me an idea to make this work

Tasks

- Create a collection view of 6 items
- Make it display in 4 rows, ie 1st    item full width of screen and
  last one too

  Help with code if possible

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a check for 1st and last row/item of the collection cell inside `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` and give corresponding size

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == dataArray.count - 1  {
        return CGSizeMake(fullWidth, height) // for 1st and last item/cell
    }else{
        return CGSizeMake(halfWidth, height) //for all items/cells
    }
}
```

To get screen width:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

let screenWidth = screenSize.width
```

Comment: how to set width with respect to screen size

Comment: Updated the answer!

Comment: Given info will be enough hint to resolve the issue.

Comment: yes i can resolve it